# Money obtained by selling Tikrovet avoda zara

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, maseches-kiddushin, masecheth-avodah-zarah, issurei-hanaa

Talmud Kiddushin 58a says that Avoda Zara 'catches its value' (תופס דמיו) to be forbidden as itself: the money obtained from its sale is also forbidden.

Now, what with *tikrovet avoda zara* (offerings to an idol)? We know that in itself it is also forbidden (AZ 29b). But is the money derived from its sale also forbidden?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the money derived from the sale of Tikrovet Avoda Zara is forbidden.

Rambam AZ 7.2.   Tikrovet has the same din as AZ itself. This din is extracted from the Mishna AZ dad 29b, Gemara 32b (a zevach compared to dead that is prohibited from hanaa) , as stated in the OP.

> ז, ב עבודה זרה עצמה, ומשמשיה, **ותקרובת שלה**, וכל הנעשה בשבילה--  **אסור בהנאה**, שנאמר "ולא תביא תועבה אל ביתך" (דברים ז,כו).  וכל הנהנה באחד מכל אלו, לוקה שתיים--אחת משום "ולא תביא תועבה אל ביתך", ואחת משום "ולא ידבק בידך מאומה, מן החרם" (דברים יג,יח).‏

Rambam AZ 7.9. If there are sold, the money is asur behanaa.All gain from idolatry, ... and from tikrovet, is prohibited as idolatry itself. This is extracted from the Gemara Kiddushin 58 (things that come from AZ, including money from selling) as stated in the question. But additionally the Rambam extends the din of damim to Tikrovet. The svara is obvious. The din Tikrovet is deorayta because of the drasha, so all dins of AZ, including damim are extended to Tikrovet.

> ז,יב  **עבר ומכר עבודה זרה, או אחד ממשמשיה, או תקרובת שלה--הרי הדמים אסורין בהנאה**; ואוסרין בכל שהן כעבודה זרה, שנאמר "והיית חרם כמוהו" (דברים ז,כו):  כל שאתה מביא מעבודה זרה, ומכל משמשיה ותקרובתה--הרי הוא כמוה.  .‏